# Issue with YOLOv8 model for object detection when using image URL from Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am currently working with the YOLOv8 model for object detection, and I am facing an issue when trying to provide an image URL from my Firebase Storage. Specifically, when I use the Firebase Storage image URL as input to the model, I receive the following error message:

```
{
    "message": "An error occurred",
    "error": "Request failed with status code 400"
}
```

To troubleshoot this problem, I have tested the model's functionality by using image URLs from other websites like unsplash.com, and in those cases, I obtained the expected results. However, when I attempt to use an image URL from Firebase Storage, I encounter the aforementioned error.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights on why the YOLOv8 model might not be able to access image URLs from Firebase Storage. Additionally, if there are any recommended improvements or modifications to my approach that would make it more appropriate and effective, I would be eager to learn about them.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!